# Given a list of 2D points and a square grid size, return the coordinate closest to the most points

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Here's a summarized problem statement from an interview I had:

> There is an `n x n` grid representing a city, along with a list of `k`
>   3-tuples `(x, y, w)`, where `(x, y)` is the coordinate of an event,
>   and `w` is the the "worth" of the event. You're also given a radius
>   `r`, which represents how far you can see. You derive happiness `h` from seeing an event, and `h=w/d`, where `d` is (1 + Euclidean distance to the event) (to account for 0 distance). If `d` is greater than `r`, then the happiness is 0. Output a coordinate `(x,y)` that has the highest cumulative happiness.

I didn't really know how to approach this problem other than brute forcing through each possible coordinate and calculating the happiness at each point, recording the max. I also thought about calculating the center of mass of the points and finding the closest integer coordinates to the center of mass, but that doesn't properly take into account the "worth" of the event.

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: All points are integers!

Comment: maybe a subset of this problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Answer (score 2):

*(I can't see an obvious best algorithm or data structure for this; it could be one of those questions where they wanted to hear your thought process more than your solution.)*

Of the two obvious approaches:

- Iterating over all locations and measuring the distance to all events to calculate the location's worth
- Iterating over all events and adding to the worth of the locations in the circle around them

the latter seems to be the most efficient one. You're never looking at worthless locations, and to distribute the worth, you only need to calculate one octant of the circle and then mirror it for the rest of the circle.

You obviously need the memory space to store a rectangular grid of the locations' worth, so that's a consideration. And if you don't know the city size beforehand, you'd have to iterate over the input once just to choose the grid size. (In contrast, the first method would require almost no memory space).

Time complexity-wise, you'd iterate over *k* events, and for each of these you'd have to calculate the worth of a number of locations related to *r<sup>2</sup>*. You can keep a maximum while you're iterating over the events, so finding the maximum value doesn't add to the time complexity. (In the first method, you'd obviously have to calculate all the same *w/(d+1)* values, without the advantage of mirroring one octant of a circle, plus at least the distance of all the additional worthless locations.)

If the number of events and the affected regions around them are small compared to the city size, the advantage of the second method is obvious. If there are a large number of events and/or *r* is large, the difference may not be significant.

There may be some mathematical tricks to decide which events to check first, or which to ignore, or when to stop, but you'd have to know some more details for that, e.g. whether two events can happen at the same location. There could e.g. be an advantage in sorting the events by worth and looking at the events with the most worth first, because at some point it may become obvious that events outside of a "hot spot" around the current maximum can be ignored. But much would depend on the specifics of the data.

---

UPDATE

When distributing the worth of an event over the locations around it, you obviously don't have to calculate the distances more than once; e.g. if *r = 3* you'd make this 7×7 grid with *1/d* weights:

```
0      0      0      0.250  0      0      0
0      0.261  0.309  0.333  0.309  0.261  0
0      0.309  0.414  0.500  0.414  0.309  0
0.250  0.333  0.500  1.000  0.500  0.333  0.250
0      0.309  0.414  0.500  0.414  0.309  0
0      0.261  0.309  0.333  0.309  0.261  0
0      0      0      0.250  0      0      0
```

Which contains only eight different values. Then you'd use this as a template to overlay on top of the grid at the location of an event, and multiply the event's worth with the weights and add them to each location's worth.

---

UPDATE

I considered the possibility that only locations with an event could be the location with the highest worth, and without the limit *r* that would be true. That would make the problem quite different. However, it's easy to create a counter-example; consider e.g. these events:

```
-      -      60     -      -
-      -      -      -      -
60     -      -      -      60
-      -      -      -      -
-      -      60     -      -
```

With a limit *r* greater than 4, they would create this worth in the locations around them:

```
61.92  73.28  103.3  73.28  61.92
73.28  78.54  82.08  78.54  73.28
103.3  82.08  80.00  82.08  103.3
73.28  78.54  82.08  78.54  73.28
61.92  73.28  103.3  73.28  61.92
```

And the locations with the highest worth 103.3 are the locations of the events. However, if we set the limit *r = 2*, we get:

```
40     30     60     30     40
30     49.7   30     49.7   30
60     30     80     30     60
30     49.7   30     49.7   30
40     30     60     30     40
```

And the location in the middle, which doesn't have an event, is now the location of maximum worth 80.

This means that locations without events, at least those within the convex hull around a cluster of events, have to be considered. Of course, if two clusters of events are found to be more than *2 × r* away from each other, they can be treated as separate zones. In that case, you wouldn't have to create a grid for the whole city, but separate smaller grids around every cluster.

---

So the overall approach would be:

- Create the square grid of size *2 × r* with the weights.
- Separate the events into clusters with a distance of more than *2 × r* between them.
- For each cluster of events, create the smallest rectangular grid that fits around the events.
- For each event, use the weight grid to distribute worth over the rectangular grid.
- While adding worth to locations, keep track of the maximum worth.